# How do the upvote / downvote arrows submit the action to Stack Overflow?

Tags: html, events

I see the HTML

```
<a class="vote-up-off" title="This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear">up vote</a>
```

But I don't see how the action submitting back to the server is performed.  I expected to see JavaScript or a form submit.  Is the CSS class doing that somehow?

Comment: Watch the browser's network tab when performing the action.

Comment: It's not the CSS per se - it's JavaScript attaching the action to the button later.

Comment: Please do not migrate this to Meta. It does not belong there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Stack Overflow website. But it isn't, really. It's completely on-topic.

Answer (score 10):

StackOverflow uses Javascript code to listen for click events.
This is called [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

In general, mixing Javascript code with HTML is a bad idea.  Content, style, and logic should be kept separate.

Comment: So it handles the click event and decides what to do based on the css class or hidden _id_ input?

Comment: @rjdevereux: It handles click events for elements with that class.